# Issue with importing material ui icons of action category

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I was trying to import material-ui icon called "minimize" which is under action category from [Material-ui icons](https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline)

I was able to import other icons like access-alarm,expand_more of different/same categories directly like below:

```
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';

import AccessAlarm from '@material-ui/icons/AccessAlarm';
```

But when I try to import minimize icon , it is giving unresolved path to module.

```
import Minimize from '@material-ui/icons/Minimize';
```

Please help me in importing this icon in right-way.

Comment: Can you please add the exact code of import and error alert you are receiving?
Here is the sandbox where all three icons are working - https://codesandbox.io/s/p77y46w0zj

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be an issue with versions used.